# Showing google maps on a dialog

Tags: android

I have an activity that extends MapActivity.
I want to show map inside a dialog in this activity.
i.e when I click a button it will show a dialog with a mapview, but this crashes because it is howing this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `MapActivity` and set its theme like `Dialog`

Comment: I tried this - android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" But it's making my Activity a Dialog. I want to have a Dialog with Maps inside this Activity.

Comment: as it is mandatory to map inside a map activity, it is not possible.

Comment: I'v done this as stated and it works. My dialog styled map is being shown over another map, however the map seems darker than usual. ie. the shading that occurs around the edges of a dialog seems to be also (only) occurring on my MapFragment, the rest of the dialog view is shown unshaded. Any ideas why this would be?